# One record but select two without Union clause, how to?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a table like this..

| taxtype | taxable | taxfree |
| --- | --- | --- |
| mixed | 10 | 20 |

My question is, how to get the outcome like this without **Union** clause?

| taxtype | taxable | taxfree |
| --- | --- | --- |
| taxable | 10 | 0 |
| taxfree | 0 | 20 |

which means, this is not what I am looking for

```
select taxtype,taxable,taxfree into #tb
from (values('mixed',10,20)) tb(taxtype,taxable,taxfree)

select 'taxable' taxtype,
        taxable,
        0 taxfree
from #tb
union all
select 'taxfree',
        0,
        taxfree
from #tb

drop table if exists #tb
```

Comment: You really need some kind of union here to generate the additional rows.

Comment: Why do you need an answer without union clause?

Comment: @NishantGupta Just curious if there is any code can be more concisely.

Comment: Bear in mind, in SQL you tell the system *what you want*, not *how to do it*. Any query that *logically* is producing the equivalent of a union should end up being processed *identically* to the same query expressed as a union. Prefer *simple readable code* over trying to be overly "clever" in expressing your queries.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks, I'm trying to meet 'simple readable' and 'concise' at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use table values constructor

```
select v.*
from   #tb t
       cross apply
       (
           values
           ('taxable', taxable, 0),
           ('taxfree', 0, taxfree)
       ) v (taxtype, taxable, taxfree)
```

Comment: I like your answer, smart.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, despite of the smart support of Squirrel, I accepted **Union** as my final solution.
Just to add some revision..

```
select taxtype,taxable,taxfree into #src
from (
        values
        ('taxable',5,0),
        ('taxfree',0,10),
        ('mixed',15,20)
    ) src(taxtype,taxable,taxfree)

select  res.*
from    #src s
        cross apply
        (select *
        from (
               values
               ('taxable', s.taxable, 0, s.taxtype),
               ('taxfree', 0, s.taxfree, s.taxtype)
        ) v (taxtype, taxable, taxfree, origin)
        where not (v.taxable = 0 and v.taxfree = 0)) res

drop table if exists #src
```